# Using 'scope' as a column name in Rails 2.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to now if I can use 'scope' as a column name safely in Rails 2.10 .

PS: if you have a list of "not to use column name table for Rails" it will be cool too :) !

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use scope as it is in the list here (in the **Other Names Reported to Have Caused Trouble** section), it is always safer to rename your column name.

http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/reservedwords